# how to flip flip STRING and decimal/ float values in array PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, ranking

I am trying to make a app that allow me to rank and sort decimal number according to it's value , but array_flip function can't flip string and decimal number ,

```
 <?php

$myarray = array(1,0.334,-0.334,-1);

//create a copy and sort
$myarray_copy = $myarray;
rsort($myarray_copy);
//reverses key and values
$myarray_copy = array_flip($myarray_copy);
//create result by using keys from sorted values + 1
foreach($myarray as $val)
    $myarray2[] = ($myarray_copy[$val]+1);
//print final array
print_r($myarray2);
print_r($myarray);


?>
```

and there is a warning about array_flip

> Warning: array_flip() [function.array-flip]: Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in C:\xampp\htdocs\ranking.php on line 9

, do you guys know how to deal with these ? is there any solution ?

Comment: You need to convert the values of the array to a string to make it as easy as possible. For example, you can concatenate 'i' to each value. Then, the values will be valid index values for the flip.

Comment: You can declare the array values as `array("1","0.334","-0.334","-1");` but do `rsort($myarray_copy,SORT_NUMERIC)` to force numeric sort.

Comment: Why do you want to flip the array? If you need to maintain the key–value asociation and sort by value, use `arsort` or `asort`. Be clearer about your intended goal.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/pBK6R I think this is enough.

Comment: how about i multiply every decimal to 1000 ,and turn it to integer then i flip it ? can we do that ?

Answer (score 0):

After sort use array_walk to convert each item from decimal to string like ---

```
function test_alter(&$item1, $key)
{
    $item1 = (string)$item1;
}
array_walk($fruits, 'test_alter', 'fruit');
```

And then flip it. Hope this helps.

Comment: how to convert decimal to integer ?